# How can I efficiently create a sliding window view of a dask array picture stack? (shrink array with index as middle point)

Tags: bigdata, dask, sliding-window

I have computed the optical flow for a stack of pictures, consisting of 100 images. Each image has dimensions of 1024x1024 pixels. These images are stored in a Dask array with the shape *(100, 100, 1024, 1024)*.

In this array, the first dimension represents the picture number, the second dimension represents the picture to which the optical flow was calculated, and the third and fourth dimensions represent the x and y values of the pictures, respectively.

Now, I would like to reduce the size of this Dask array to include only a window of the second dimension. For each entry in the first dimension, there should only be 11 entries in the second dimension. This means there is a fixed window size with the index of the first dimension as the middle point.

Using slicing, this can be achieved for one entry in the first dimension as follows: **array[10, 5:15, ...]**.

The resulting array should have the shape *(100, 11, 1024, 1024)*.

I have heard about the sliding window function of NumPy/Dask **(da.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view)**, but I'm having trouble combining it with editing the index.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import dask.array as da

array = da.random.random((100, 100, 1024, 1024))

window_size = 11

test1 = da.pad(array, [(0,0), ((window_size/2), (window_size/2)), (0,0), (0,0)])

test2 = da.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(test1, (1, 1, window_size, 1))
```

Efficiency is crucial due to the size of the input array. Therefore, I believe that calculating a new view with this approach is a good starting point.

I would appreciate any input or suggestions.